# how to get distinct (data) with id and without using aggregatefunction to the id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I want Distinct data Agent like this.

```
Id       Agent                  

2471    A   
2765    B
2955    C      
1770    D   
2431    F   
2981    H   
2460    M   
1739    R
2040    S
2023    T   
1692    V
```

I am using this query:

```
SELECT  max(propertyid) as propertyid , agent_name
FROM         dbo.properties
WHERE     (agent_name NOT IN ('null', '')) group by agent_name
```

I am created this query for a view but i want to use the view in MVC model. But this view cannot accept the model,because here is not have the primary key or foreign key.
this table contains Id is the primary key, but i am using the aggregate function  with Id ,that changed to the ordinary field.

please reply to me.

Comment: what actually the result? and from where you get the resulted data?

Comment: I want distinct agent name with Id

Comment: did you tried the answer?

Answer (score 2):

This will returns the same result . try this

```
;WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agent_name ORDER BY propertyid DESC) AS rno,
          propertyid ,
          agent_name
    FROM  dbo.properties
    WHERE  ISNULL(agent_name,'') !=''

    )
    SELECT propertyid ,agent_name
    FROM cte 
    WHERE rno=1
```

Comment: How can i write query as a view